# Stop ffmpeg rtmp live stream without cutting off video

Tags: ffmpeg

I can stream fine using the command

`ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 \
-i :0.0+0,0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k \
-vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
-f flv rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/<stream key>`

Platforms generally have a delay of ~10 seconds for viewers. When I terminate the ffmpeg command, the stream ends immediately for the viewers and they miss the last 10 seconds of video.

How can I terminate the stream without the end of the video cutting off abruptly?

Comment: As long as ffmpeg has flushed all its encoded data, it's upto the platform to consume and process all received data.

Comment: @Gyan it seems like ffmpeg automatically sends the `deleteStream` netstream command referenced here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf when the stream is over. Do you know how to disable this?

Comment: Can't be avoided. ffmpeg will issue when it has to close the streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Are you sure about this? It doesn’t seem to issue the command if it is SIGKILL. Is there maybe some timeout flag I could use so that it hangs around for a bit?

Comment: With SIGKILL, the shell terminates ffmpeg so no graceful cleanup.